# filter post regex in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

Q1: i am trying to capture abc-12345 type pattern with regex and using

```
'[aA-zZ]+\-[0-9]+'
```

I am getting most results that are correct but a few are coming back with the [ like '[abc-57489'. whats the best way to fix the column in sql to removew the '['

Q2: to capture more scenarios, i am doing:

```
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'[aA-zZ]+\-[0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'[aA-zZ]+\- [0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'[aA-zZ]+\ - [0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'[aA-zZ]+\ -[0-9]+'),'')))) as columnoneadjusted,
```

How Can i filter out items post regex that dont have 'abc'

Comment: You got multiple options: 1. use if condition 2. Use case condition 3. Use try function. Refer to this link: https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler answer.

```
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'(abc)+\-[0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'(abc)+\- [0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'(abc)+\ - [0-9]+'),
coalesce(regexp_extract(column1,'(abc)+\ -[0-9]+'),'')))) as columnoneadjusted,
```